# Create singed S3 download link w/ signature algorithm version 4

Tags: php, url, amazon-s3, signing

i need expiring downloadlinks for a bucket in eu-central-1.

With `$s3->getObjectUrl($bucket, $filename, '+5 minutes');` from the SDK-PHP i only getting unsinged URLs like http://.../file.txt without the querystring.

Complete Code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
    'signature'    => 'v4',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'xxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxx'
    ]
]);

$plainUrl = $client->getObjectUrl('mybucket', 'data.txt');
// > https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/data.txt

$signedUrl = $client->getObjectUrl('mybucket', 'data.txt', '+10 minutes');
// > https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/data.txt
```

I don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhh,
`getObjectUrl` no longer has a third parameter.
This Works:

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'test1G.dat'
]);

$request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```